# Remove caracters after caracters in list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

So let's say I got this list:

```
["My favorite apple Ben", "I need my apple Jean", "I like really like apple pies which walk"]
```

and the output should be:

```
["Ben", "Jean", "pies which walk"]
```

So basically remove everything before a string `apple` and maybe the string `apple` itself in a list in Python.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you show where you're stuck in the code ? Any error ?

Comment: inp = [''.join(x for x in string if not x in "apple") for string in inp:], that ":" gave me an error

Comment: `newlist = [i.split('apple')[1] for i in yourlist]` should do the trick.

Comment: nope newlist = [i.split('apple')[1] for i in inp]
               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I assume `inp` has strings that don't contain the substring `apple` then? Please add appropriate sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `split()` function :

```py
# Returns an array containing what is before and after each occurrence of "apple", here ["My dear ", " Frederick"] (notice the spaces before and after the strings)
my_array = "My dear apple Frederick".split("apple")
```

If you know you only have one occurrence of "apple", writing something like `"My dear apple Frederick".split("apple")[1:]` should do the job : you remove the first element of the list, that would be the part of the string before the separator "apple", and keep everything else.

If you want to keep the separator, you can concatenate it :

```py
sep = "apple"
my_string = sep + "".join("My dear apple Frederick".split(sep)[1:])
```

You also can remove any leading spaces by using `lstrip()` : `my_string = "".join("My dear apple Frederick".split(sep)[1:]).lstrip()`

Comment: assuming multiple apples, and you wanted the string after the last apple, you can do [-1] as well

Comment: Would also suggest using `lstrip()` to get rid of any leading spaces.

Comment: `lstrip()` is a method of `str`, so just call it right after `split(sep)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
myList = ["My favorite apple Ben", "I need my apple Jean", "I like really like apple pies which walk"]

newList = []

position = 0
while position <= len(myList)-1:
    appleIndex = myList[position].index("apple")
    excludingAppleIndex = appleIndex + len("apple") + 1

    newList.append(myList[position][excludingAppleIndex:])

    position += 1

print(newList)
```

Let me break it down for you:

1. I created a variable called "newList" which will store values after the word "apple" from the "myList" list.
2. I created a variable called "position" which tracks the index of the elements of "myList" list.
3. The while loop will run until it reaches the end element of the "myList" list.
4. The variable "appleIndex" will find the index of the word "apple" in the respected string, which here is a element from "myList" list.
5. The variable "excludingAppleIndex" will exclude "appleIndex" adding to it length of the word(apple) because "appleIndex" will just give you the starting index of the word and not the slice index of the word. Adding 1 to it at the end because of the whitespace.
6. Then the line "newList.append(myList[position][excludingAppleIndex:])" just appends the rest of respected string to the empty list(newList)

Hope it helps.